# I need help adding a string to a new line in .asm file

Tags: assembly

```
BITS 16
start:
mov ax, 07C0h 
add ax, 288 
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096
mov ax, 07C0h 
mov ds, ax
mov si, boot_message 
call print_string 
jmp $ 
boot_message db 'test1', 0
print_string: 
mov ah, 0Eh 
.repeat:
lodsb 
cmp al, 0 
je .done 
int 10h 
jmp .repeat
.done:
ret
times 510-($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xAA55
```

i am trying to replace string 'test 1' with 3 strings each on a line.
the output should be similar to:

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

Comment: You've changed too much of question. If you have an other question you should post it separately.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have a large part of that already done. Let's go through your code once again

```
BITS 16
start:
    mov ax, 0x8D00  ; 0x7c00 + 0x100 + 0x1000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096    ; this is your stack, not particulary important here...

    mov ax, 0x07C0  ; the start of the boot sector in memory
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, string_1        ; load the string to be printed out
    call print_string       ; print it

    mov si, string_2        
    call print_string 

    mov si, string_3        
    call print_string 

    jmp $           ; halt the execution here


print_string: 
    xor bh, bh      ; set page number to 0x00
    mov bl, 0x0F    ; white characters on black background
    mov ah, 0x0E    ; int 0x10 function: teletype output
    .repeat:
        lodsb 
        test al, al
        je .done 

        int 10h 
        jmp .repeat
    .done:
        ret

; - STRINGS -
string_1 db 'test 1', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
string_2 db 'test 2', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
string_3 db 'test 3', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00

times 510-($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xAA55
```

The key here is to add

- `0x0D` (ASCII Carriage Return) to return the cursor back to beginning of the line
- `0x0A` (ASCII Line Feed / New Line) to go to the next line

at the end of all of your strings.

Comment: Yes, but I'd also add `0x0D` to `0x0A` in order to return the cursor at the beginning of the line.